# Call request by request Alamofire swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I wonder how I could make the request executed one by one. It's about image processing. And the server cannot process more than one image. The problem is that I need to send 10 pictures at a time, and if I send everything at once, I have a problem with the timeout, and now I'm interested in how to send the next request when response from the previous one arrives?

```
func clearingImage() {
    if clearingImageArray.count < 0 || indexOfClearImage >= clearingImageArray.count
    {
        guard let imageName = ImageFilenameUtilities.getNameOfImageFromPath(filePath: clearingImageArray[indexOfClearImage]) else
        {
            indexOfClearImage+=1
            clearingImage()
            return
         }
        guard let clearType = ImageFilenameUtilities.getClearTypeFromFilename(filename: imageName) else
        {
            indexOfClearImage+=1
            clearingImage()
            return
        }
        guard let image = gallery?.getImageForPath(path: clearingImageArray[indexOfClearImage]) else
        {
            indexOfClearImage+=1
            clearingImage()
            return
        }
                   sendImageToServer(image: image, imageName: imageName)
    }
}
func sendImageToServer(image:UIImage,imageName:String)
    {
        let url = "example.com"
     let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
            "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
            // "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 12000
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 12000
        
        manager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipleData in
            for (key, value) in parameter {
                multipleData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            multipleData.append(
                imageData, withName: "image", fileName: imageName, mimeType: "image/jpg")}, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers){
                    (result) in
                    switch result {
                        
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            self.indexOfClearImage += 1
                            if let image = UIImage(data: response.data!) {
                                //save image to galery
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if let error = response.result.error {
                                    if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                                    self.indexOfClearImage -= 1
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        //send next image to server
                        self.indexOfClearImage += 1
                    }
           }
            self.clearingImage()
        }
```

Comment: What does code for sending one request (and getting a response) look like?

Comment: @PhillipMills now i  call recursively but I don’t know I have any better and more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

Just send the 2nd request on the 1st completion block, when you get the response, and so on.

```
func firstRequest() {
    AF.request("url/here").response { response in
        self.secondRequest()
    }
}

func secondRequest() {
    AF.request("url/here").response { response in
        // call 3rd request and so on...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I don't know how many pictures I have. I can have 1-2-30